# How to list user as file owner when user belongs to group on Windows 7/Windows Server 2008

Tags: file, account, ownership

When our IT person added my Domain User Account to a Group Account, files which I created listed Group Account Name as Owner instead of my User Account Name. Is there a way to attach user to file ownership even if the user is in a group?

Comment: Windows 7 and WindowsServer 2008